# Having trouble accessing the arguments to the git pre-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am running vanilla git (git version 2.23.3) as origin master of a bare repository on an AWS instance.

I have created a file repo_dir/hooks/pre-receive with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

echo $1 > pre-receive-old-hash.txt
echo $2 > pre-receive-new-hash.txt
echo $3 > pre-receive-ref.txt

exit 1
```

I make a test push from my remote.  I can confirm that hook is run, as I get the push rejected.

However,  while the pre-receive-x.txt files exist, they are empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From `githooks` manual: "_pre-receive: ... This hook executes once for the receive operation. It takes no arguments,..._ So don't except `${1..3}` to be defined. Read the standard input, instead, from which the hook receives extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive

> It takes no arguments, but for each ref to be updated it **receives on standard input** a line of the format:

> `<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF`

(Emphasize mine — *phd*)

Make your script this:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

while read old new refname; do
    echo $old >> pre-receive-old-hash.txt
    echo $new >> pre-receive-new-hash.txt
    echo $refname >> pre-receive-ref.txt
done

exit 1
```